# Auto resizing mask broken on iOS 8

Tags: ios, user-interface, autoresizingmask

My app was working perfectly until QA spotted some UI elements miss-aligned. The label was too far too the right, I looked at the auto resizing masks and they were correct!! I had flexible width on it which was correct. So to fix it I took it off and that actually worked.

I don't understand how thats solved the problem? And also I've never touched this code/UI so it's randomly broken and then the fix means taking away the logic thats meant to work?

Has anything changed in auto resizing masks with iOS 8 or recently?

Comment: No. I have a project with autoresizing masks and it's working correctly. One problem you might have is that views go under the navigation bar. We can't help you debug without seeing 1) How it looks. 2) How you want it to look. 3) What did you do to get the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Yes your right. It seems I added some custom transition code to my root view controller which somehow affected auto resizing masks. Thanks for the quick reply.